# Simple 2 line jQuery Accordion menu...Need help !

Tags: accordion

This is my accordion menu :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
$("dt.title").click(function()
{ $("div.info").slideUp("slow"); $(this).next("div.info:hidden").slideDown("normal" );
});
});
</script>
```

It is working fine, here have a look at the html:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="container">

<ul id="nav">
<dt class="title"><a href="#">About</a></dt>
<dt class="title"><a href="#">Work</a></dt>
<div class="info">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Bol</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Annie</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Imran</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<dt class="title"><a href="#">Contact</a></dt>
<dt class="title"><a href="#">Links</a></dt>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Very simple ! But when I put the href links, the menu stop working. For example:

```
<dt class="title"><a href="about.html">About</a></dt>
```

Please help me with this, I'll be really thankful !

Cheers,

Comment: i think you made asked this question again. delete the redundant data